# tfs 2013 Required parameter when queueing new build?

Tags: tfsbuild

Is there a way to add a required parameter just when queueing new build? I have already tried to mark this parameter in the "Process Parameters Metadata Editor" as "Required" and "only when queuing a build". 
Yet, builds can be queued though parameter was not populated.

Any Idea?